# Data structure with O(n) initialization and O(logn) insertion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Is  there any data structure that let me initialize is with a running time of O(n) and insert to in O(logn) ??

Comment: Does need to handle any other operations? If not, a structure that does nothing upon initialization and ignores all insertions does it all in `O(1)`.

Comment: No. If insertion is O(lgn), then inserting n elements (or initializing) is n* O(lgn) or O(nlgn).

Comment: It needs to handle findmin - O(1) & deletemin - O(logn)

Comment: @Natezone I think you look for a heap.

Answer (score 0):

HashMap O(1) for insert and random access

Comment: A short addition to this response, HashMap has **average** O(1) for insert and random access.

Comment: I couldnt use the HashMap because it is O(1), the insertion must be O(logn)

Answer (score 0):

C++ `std::set` takes O(nlog(n)) to initialize and O(log(n)) to insert / remove.
finding min / max elements takes O(1) using: `begin` , `end` which returns an iterator to first/last element in sorted set.

Answer (score 0):

The structure that initializes in O(n), inserts in O(logn), findmin (peek) - O(1) and deletemin - O(logn) is Min-Heap - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap.